# CSS: Flip a div on hover. Front and back content not hiding with flip on phone

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations

I am spaced out here as my site is working in iphone view in chrome in the developer tool but when I launch the website on my iphone itself, it looks skewed.

Anyway, I have multiple divs on my home page. Divs show just a title and when I hover over them, I want them to flip on y axis in place, hide the title and show more details.

Everything works on my macbook and imac, but when I head over to my iphone, the details show overlapping on the title when I load the page. When I hover over the content flips but stays overlapped. On the Macbook and Imac, the front content goes away and back content shows with the flip so it works as I want.

What am I doing wrong? Here is a picture

[image: Div showing overlapping front and back contents]

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="flip-container col-md-4" ng-repeat="webinar in webinars" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
             <div class="flipper">
                 <div class="front">
              <!-- front content -->
                    <h3>
                      {{ webinar.title }}
                    </h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class="back">
                  <!-- back content -->
                    <p>{{ webinar.description | limitTo: 100 }}</p>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="getOneWebinar(webinar)" class="btn btn-default center">Learn more</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(65,61,160);
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 360px;
    height: 320px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
  /*text-align: center;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front h3{
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-right: 8%;
}
.back p{
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 33%;
}
.back a{
  margin-left: 11%;
  /*margin-top: 33%;*/
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you on?

Comment: Latest one on the phone. @Amir5000

Comment: Up to v 8.4 you need to include the -webkit- prefix for all the CSS 3 transforms you are doing as well as the transform properties like backface-visibility and transition. check out http://caniuse.com/ for reference. I don't know what else could be the issue honestly.

Comment: that worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to v 8.4 you need to include the -webkit- prefix for all the CSS 3 transforms you are doing as well as the transform properties like backface-visibility and transition. check out caniuse.com for reference. I don't know what else could be the issue honestly.